# 3D environment mouse capture via remote desktop

Tags: 14.04, mouse, remote-desktop, chromebook, 3d

I'm currently on a Chromebook running Ubuntu 14.04 and have my desktop PC at home running Windows 10. I want to be able to run a 3D modeling software on my desktop PC and operate it from my Chromebook remotely. However, when I set up a remote desktop connection to my desktop everything works correctly until I try to navigate the 3D environment in the program (which would normally capture the mouse in the window.) Instead of moving the camera to wherever I move the mouse, it just snaps back to the center of the window with the pointer still showing. The 3D window's camera is just stuck looking up with the cursor showing and locked in place.

I was wondering if there was a workaround to this that is compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 that I could use. Keep in mind that it doesn't have to have super fast smooth FPS. I can easily do the same work with low(ish) FPS, so it's not an issue with transfer speed and connection quality. Basically, I just want a solution/workaround that would let me control the modeling software as I normally would if I were operating the desktop PC in person.

---

**EDIT:** I have read up on articles that say that you tweak some settings on Microsoft Remote Desktop to get it to capture the mouse, but this solution isn't compatible with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You don't state it, but are you using Ubuntu 14.04 on your Chromebook?  Also are you using remmina for your remote desktop connection?

Comment: @ThatGuy I'm open to any software for RDP, but I'm currently using Chrome remote desktop. At the bottom, it says Ubuntu 14.04, but I'll put it closer to the top as well.

Comment: Something that's really helpful, is screenshots of the symptoms.  Are you able to take a couple and post them as well? :)